# Generate topographical index from a digital surface model (DSM) to generate a flood susceptibility map

Tags: lidar, random-forest, flood, topographic-wetness-index

I'm performing a random forest model to generate a flood susceptibility map, I have LiDAR data from the study area where I generated Digital Surface Model (DSM) and Digital Terrain Model (DTM) raster files, the Topographic Wetness Index (TWI) is commonly used to quantify topographic control on hydrological processes, but when calculating the TWI of the DTM the results don't seem correct. My question would be whether it makes sense to use the TWI index based on the DSM, since generating the results obtained from it seem to make more sense. Also should I use a Hydrologic Reconditioning DEM/DTM?

The equation that am I using for calculating TWI is:

- TWI = Ln(FA_scaled / tan_slope)
- FA_scaled = Scaled Flow Accumulation.

OBS: The DTM data are generated disregarding the buildings, then the regions are interpolated.

**Left: TWI using DSM; Right: TWI using DTM**
[image: Left: TWI (DSM); Right: TWI (DTM)]

Comment: So what's that image you are showing, what's what?  Without a legend to interpret it no one has any idea what you are showing... Also might help if you explain what TWI means, not everyone is a flood specialist? Amend your question.